# Why setup.py fails in pyBigWig installation?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

Hi verybody I am trying to install RSeQC but I got an error installing pyBigWig.

I am using a conda environment with python 3.8.

The OS is a Windows 10 Pro.

```
(python3.8) C:\Users\me>pip --version
pip 22.1.2 from C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\python3.8\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

(python3.8) C:\Users\me>pip install RSeQC
Collecting RSeQC
  Downloading RSeQC-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 133.6/133.6 kB 438.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting bx-python
  Downloading bx-python-0.8.13.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.4/1.4 MB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cython>=0.17
  Using cached Cython-0.29.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (985 kB)
Collecting pyBigWig
  Downloading pyBigWig-0.3.18.tar.gz (64 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 64.8/64.8 kB 699.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j0xpd3pz\pybigwig_d3408484097f434884b2c8954968140e\setup.py", line 24, in <module>
          for e in sysconfig.get_config_vars('BLDLIBRARY')[0].split():
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Hope anyone can help with this issue.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('BLDLIBRARY'))"` ?

Comment: Generally, I recommend bioinformatics Windows users to run WSL, install Mambaforge (for linux), and configure Bioconda. Or, use Docker + Biocontainers (everything package on Bioconda is available in container format).